# Update Progress not working inside Gridview in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, updateprogress

I want to show PreLoader on button click inside Gridview.
But it is not working as expected .

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_deparment" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gvPurchaseInvoiceEntry_RowCommand"
                                    AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_deparment_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="gv_deparment_Sorting"
                                    HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="false" CssClass="gvstyling gridview_width_100" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="Record(s) Not Found!">
                                    <Columns>

                                        <asp:BoundField
                                            DataField="department"
                                            HeaderText="Department"
                                            SortExpression="department" />

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="10">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server"            UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="cmdUpdate"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Update </asp:LinkButton>
                                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_departmnt" Value='<%#  Eval("department_id")%>' runat="server" />
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ck_departmnt" OnCheckedChanged="ck_departmnt_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("isactive") %>' />
                                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                                    <Triggers>
                                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdate" EventName="Click" />
                                                    </Triggers>



                                                </asp:UpdatePanel>




                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update Message"  ItemStyle-Width="200">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgressdf1"     runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID" Visible="true">
                                                    <ProgressTemplate>
                                                        <img src="../img/spinner-mini.gif" />
                                                        &nbsp; Please Wait...
                                                    </ProgressTemplate>
                                                </asp:UpdateProgress>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

**This is the problem that I am facing.
On single button click, only preloader besides the button should be display.**
Here is the Image
[image]

But unfortunately all the preloader are displaying on single button click.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: if you wrap your code with update pnl loader will be previewed for each asyn request

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar I have achieved the same functionality earlier also but dont know why I am facing this problem now

Answer (score 0):

I think cause is you are not setting AssociatedUpdatePanelID . This link might help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I have also tried that If i set AssociatedUpdatePanelID then updateprogress is not working. means not for a single row preloader is displaying